# how to use gdb to debug execution error?

Tags: 12.04

When I ./tata I get segmentation fault.(core dumped) So I figure I need to debug the error, but I couldn't get where the line of errors are. Therefore, I need some guidelines from experienced guys to guide me.. Thank you..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

gdb is good for debugging programs that have debug information. I don't know what tata is. If you compile it yourself you have to tell the compiler and/or the linker to include debug info in the executable. Otherwise the executable file doesn't have any knowledge about "lines". If you don't have access to the source code of tata, bad luck.

Comment: I see.. I did not compile the file tata. But it was a security challenge thing. Is there anyway to access the source code? Or how to include debug info in the executable? I tried open with gedit, and others compiler programs, but all I saw was alien words..

Comment: compiling means translating from source code to machine code. debug info means "which point in machine code belong to which line in source code". machine code knows nothing about source code lines, except if you explicitly say so at compile time. since I don't know what tata is I don't know how to get its source code.